# Rstudio - installation of package had non-zero exit status windows

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed RStudio and r-3.4.4. In RStudio, I tried to run below 3 packages.

```
install.packages("plotly")
install.packages("reticulate")
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

But i get below error

```
installation of package had non-zero exit status windows for plotly,
ggplot2 and reticulate
```

The reason I need install r-3.4.4 is that current r version supported by powerBI cloud service is r-3.4.4

Comment: Try `install.packages(c("plotly","reticulate","ggplot2"), verbose=TRUE)` and say what you get.

Comment: hello Ofek, thanks for looking into this. after investigating more on poweBI with custom HTML visual, I found that higher r version I installed 4.1.2 can works as well in poweBIdesktop. so i don't need to install r-3.4.4 now. thank you for the advice.